# Android Zbar not reading QR code

Tags: android, zbar

I am have tried following 2 libraries to read QR code(not bar code).

https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner
http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/index.html

both are reading QR Code but both libraries giving me (0104031467489264) this format of data.
I tried to read same QR code with android QR reader application "QR Droid" and it returned me complete data like (12102013|name|2012046800|110001|1620.91||||||)

Please can anyone guide me how i can read complete data of QR code using these libraries.
Following is QR Code image.

[image]

Comment: Do you know if zbar supports DataMatrix or did you end up finding about it?

Answer (score 3):

That's not a QR Code. That's a Datamatrix.

Most probably, you're getting '0104031467489264' because of a false positive (the library *thinks* it found a barcode).

If you really want to handle QR Codes, you can generate them here to test: http://qrdroid.com/generate

If you need to handle Datamatrix, double check if those libraries support them. Or you can try [ZXing](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/).

Or, if it's OK to require an external app to handle your app's scans, you can integrate to QR Droid by Intents, that's much easier. More info and sample code:
http://qrdroid.com/android-developers.php